# Having difficult time parsing this string with regex?

Tags: regex, python-3.x

```
text="""[{"token":"03AJzQf7P5tfAY0T8yGDlF_aoPkLgz9-F7aiXzvViQqaaRmcJeFuIq96vmLoPXVK1GW-Fs8xp6OmJWvFvyNa3ayMpvaLkb6R    sVkjjWBjqVIW4ziWeHk--Vrd8zVaA-Pt8VxMdoDBYxjRRrCNdeQN-Fk_-Wywb5XceJGdPJbMDZ-BoOB8l3Gq4bFwJTVu56zLT-4fbAsLWqRI7TjEswJ_y2-6NlEOyTTxFblzlZLYFh7urRx2Wra_gdP0-uUxoZydZBzbiPetcYmGo9b1B69-Pmb7akK7aqLUN03mvC3t1bn4u0ZvJGWjBmqhv81QoP3J1u-_Xh    p34_dhspsjDpgfxYcHTI3e3yAir_QQ","timestamp":"2017-10-11T23:40:13.436Z"},{"token":"03AJzQf7Mmj_KZVl39Ob1_YnvsJuj4vFS    o8ZWXNUJjSEjZqNyH8puB035sZYbQdPLVdOoX8ljyGeDYvxk6Kkf3Sc16EAS0bg0cXUAXzs6LAr3jDZmtW38TjWN5qbykIN_-s0-YpX6F0XJ4Hw3GDl    vVkxmAk1btZewbeUp1nwMeM9BGJxkJZ5_2LRCGTERPGICKU4P897_FYcduADw5j1wEd9Yp7TdczRkgkY3qpsNcxlrF_rXv7DAvUxkg2_fussc3RkRgq    ZueTMPkDN7B5BYiTBqVeXJ48Lvm6-1R86HgyrcDAPaZ1xMY0JxzMSvU26rChpomXFLERLfxijDNrixfGeh8hSCa0dX1HiLac8yOERKRcbBk1kXLOK8"    ,"timestamp":"2017-10-11T23:40:29.916Z"}]"""
```

I would like to parse out this string, and put it into a list. I only want the token value to be store in the list.

My current code (not working):

```
token = re.search('(?<="token":").*?"', text)
print(token.group(0))
print(token.group(1))
```

the output:

```
03AJzQf7P5tfAY0T8yGDlF_aoPkLgz9-F7aiXzvViQqaaRmcJeFuIq96vmLoPXVK1GW-Fs8xp6OmJWvFvyNa3ayMpvaLkb6RsVkjjWBjqVIW4ziWeHk--Vrd8zVaA-Pt8VxMdoDBYxjRRrCNdeQN-Fk_-Wywb5XceJGdPJbMDZ-BoOB8l3Gq4bFwJTVu56zLT-4fbAsLWqRI7TjEswJ_y2-6NlEOyTTxFblzlZLYFh7urRx2Wra_gdP0-uUxoZydZBzbiPetcYmGo9b1B69-Pmb7akK7aqLUN03mvC3t1bn4u0ZvJGWjBmqhv81QoP3J1u-_Xhp34_dhspsjDpgfxYcHTI3e3yAir_QQ"
```

Error for token.group(1):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 45, in <module>
     print(token.group(1))
IndexError: no such groupuUxoZydZBzbiPetcYmGo9b1B69-Pmb7akK7aqLUN03mvC3t1bn4u0ZvJGWjBmqhv81QoP3J1u-_Xhp34_dhspsjDpgfxYcHTI3e3yAir_QQ"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your text is a json string. You can use `json.loads` to convert from json string to a list of dict.

```
import json

text="""[{"token":"03AJzQf7P5tfAY0T8yGDlF_aoPkLgz9-F7aiXzvViQqaaRmcJeFuIq96vmLoPXVK1GW-Fs8xp6OmJWvFvyNa3ayMpvaLkb6R    sVkjjWBjqVIW4ziWeHk--Vrd8zVaA-Pt8VxMdoDBYxjRRrCNdeQN-Fk_-Wywb5XceJGdPJbMDZ-BoOB8l3Gq4bFwJTVu56zLT-4fbAsLWqRI7TjEswJ_y2-6NlEOyTTxFblzlZLYFh7urRx2Wra_gdP0-uUxoZydZBzbiPetcYmGo9b1B69-Pmb7akK7aqLUN03mvC3t1bn4u0ZvJGWjBmqhv81QoP3J1u-_Xh    p34_dhspsjDpgfxYcHTI3e3yAir_QQ","timestamp":"2017-10-11T23:40:13.436Z"},{"token":"03AJzQf7Mmj_KZVl39Ob1_YnvsJuj4vFS    o8ZWXNUJjSEjZqNyH8puB035sZYbQdPLVdOoX8ljyGeDYvxk6Kkf3Sc16EAS0bg0cXUAXzs6LAr3jDZmtW38TjWN5qbykIN_-s0-YpX6F0XJ4Hw3GDl    vVkxmAk1btZewbeUp1nwMeM9BGJxkJZ5_2LRCGTERPGICKU4P897_FYcduADw5j1wEd9Yp7TdczRkgkY3qpsNcxlrF_rXv7DAvUxkg2_fussc3RkRgq    ZueTMPkDN7B5BYiTBqVeXJ48Lvm6-1R86HgyrcDAPaZ1xMY0JxzMSvU26rChpomXFLERLfxijDNrixfGeh8hSCa0dX1HiLac8yOERKRcbBk1kXLOK8"    ,"timestamp":"2017-10-11T23:40:29.916Z"}]"""

mylist = json.loads(text)

token = ' '.join(mylist[0]['token'].split()).split()
```